# is there a formula to get a term from nested loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, math

I have a nested loop as follows :

```
xl = yl = [a for a in range(1,12)]
ll = [a for a in range(0,6)]
c = 0;
output = []

for x in xl:
    for y in yl:
        if (y > x):
            for l in ll :
                output.append("{0}-{1}-{2}".format(x,y,l));
                c+=1;
```

Given a value of c which is the position of a certain term, I need to get the value of that term.
For example if c = 10, I need the 10th element of output.
 it would be awesome if someone told could give me a generic formula for all nested loops.
I tried googling, but I don't even know what terms to google.

Comment: You are trying to access the 10th element in a list? What about `ll[10]`?

Comment: @Sumurai8 It's not that simple, he's trying to access the k'th element in the triplet (x,y,z) where x is in x1, y is in y1, z is in l1 and x<y. Without the x<y restriction it can be done fairly easy (accessing an address in 3D array) - but that requirement makes it harder.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I'm trying to access the 10th element in the output from the whole nested loop.

Comment: I assume that these ranges are example data, not the real data?

Comment: "a generic formula for all nested loops"  Do you mean nested loops that have the same setup (but maybe changing the end of `range`)?  Or *all* nested loops?  That would be pretty much impossible, other than just calculating every instance with a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have put the output into an array, so you can simply look at `output[10]`.

As for the bigger problem that you are trying to solve, I believe that you want to learn about generators.  Here is how you work with them.  First you put your loop in a function, and call `yield` where you want and no `return` statement.  Like so.

```
def loop_generator ():
    xl = yl = [a for a in range(1,12)]
    ll = [a for a in range(0,6)]

    for x in xl:
        for y in yl:
            if (y > x):
                for l in ll :
                    yield (x, y, 1)
```

Now `x = loop_generator()` will return a *generator*.  This is an object that, every time you call `next` on it, will start running code in the function and will return the next point `yield` would be called.  If you run out of `yield`s it will raise the `StopIteration` exception.

So your code now can be finished off with:

```
my_generator = loop_generator()
# Throw away 9 values
for i in range(9):
    next(my_generator)
# Get the one I want
x, y, l = next(my_generator)
# Show what I got.
print "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(x,y,l)
```

This strategy can be used to turn any nested loop into something that you can step through and pull values out of.

Incidentally Python's native looping constructs all know to call `next` and terminate cleanly on `StopIteration` so that the following works as you might hope:

```
for x, y, l in loop_generator():
    print "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(x,y,l)
```